# Custom Email script

Tags: forms, email, google-sheets

I am trying to form a simple order system, which responds to the user with a estimated delivery date once it is inserted into google sheet.

Basically someone completes a google form, which populates the sheet and then I require the sheet to send an email confirmation once a delivery date is manually inserted into the "delivery date" column on the sheet.

Currently the script is:

```
function CustomEmail() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("B2:L1000");
    var UserData = range.getValues();
    for (i in UserData) {
       var row = UserData[i];
       var name = row[5];
       var email = row[0];
       var score = row[9];

       MailApp.sendEmail (row[1], "ORDER CONFIRMATION", "Order Confirmation of: " + name + ". The estimated delivery date is " + score);
     }
}
```

It seems to work but it emails all of the rows of data, so I receive multiple emails each time and it will duplicate. I need it to just send an email to the row which has had the date manually inserted in the sheet. The script is designed to email an email address which is captured through the form.

I would like it to email that line only, I have read that it would be best to use an "on edit" trigger. This works but it still sends an email to the whole sheet each time not just the particular line that is edited.

The email response arrives like this:

"Order Confirmation of: 300mm screws. The estimated delivery date is Thu Jan 17 2019  00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)"

Apologies, this is my first attempt at any sort of script so very novice.

Cheers
Joe